# Тормозит анимация

Tags: java, android

Сделал имплементацию `NavigationDrawer`.

Работает так:`Drawer` состоит из `ExpandavleListView` в котором 5 групп. Фоном служит картинка из ресурсов. Картинка с высотой 5 экранов. При нажатии на группу я смещаю картинку по оси Y. Т.е., для каждой группы свой фон, который должен при выборе группы прокручиваться.

Проблема в том, что когда добавляю фрагменты, начинает тормозить анимация.

Как выйти из ситуации?

Фон двигаю вот так:

```
private void startBackgroundAnimation(int groupPosition) {

        int backgroundImageYPosition = groupPosition * mScreenHeight;
        int duration = 400;

        final TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, mLastBackgroundPosition, -backgroundImageYPosition);
        animation.setDuration(duration);
        animation.setFillAfter(true);
        mLastBackgroundPosition = +(-backgroundImageYPosition); 
        sendBackgroundAnimationCallback(groupPosition);
        drawerBackground.startAnimation(animation);
    }
```

Параметры фоновой картинки:

Картинка лежит в `drawable-nodpi`

Размер - *462x4096* `JPEG` ~380кб

```
 drawerBackground = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bg_drawer);
        drawerBackground.getLayoutParams().height = mScreenHeight * 5;
```

Comment: опять же, на многих дивайсах получите OOM. 28 мб в памяти займет картинка

Comment: И совершенно не странно, что анимация этой картинки тормозит. Это не баг, а нормальное поведение

Comment: @metalurgus Тогда что делать? Картинку сжимать?

Comment: ставьте куски картинки на фон каждому элементу отдельно.